# SQL Server 2014 AOAG Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

Have a current AOAG setup with 1 database.  Trying to add a 2nd database.  It's in `FULL` recovery mode and I performed a `FULL` backup.  When I try to add the database, it says I need a `FULL` backup and the check box is "grayed" out so I cannot select it.

I have not found anything on Google with information on this so hoping someone who is a "guru" on AOAG can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Take another backup and make sure you don't have COPY_ONLY enabled.

Comment: Which of the three options are you using in order to add the database to the AG?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this which consists of all the things you need to do before you add a DB to existing AOAG :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878487.aspx

[image]